# Calculating the derivative at x = -1 implicitly

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometric-integrals

I have a question that says to calculate the value of $dy\over dx$ at $x = -1$ when it is given that,

$$(\sin y)^{\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})}+ \frac{\sqrt3}{2}\sec^{-1}(2x)+ 2^x\tan (\log_e(x+2))=0$$

So, I differentiated it directly, which led me to the following, (first I made a mistake, I hadnt put $|x|$ in the formula for the $\sec^{-1}(2x)$, which led to the result being $0$, but I fixed that later, which led me to the following result):

$$(\sin y)^{\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})}\bigg\{ \frac{\pi}{2}\cos \bigg(\frac{\pi x}{2}\bigg)\log(\sin y)+\sin\bigg(\frac{\pi x}{2}\bigg)\cot y \frac{dy}{dx}\bigg\}+\frac{\sqrt3}{|2x|\sqrt{4x^2-1}}+2^x\log2\tan(\log(x+2))+2^x\sec^2(\log(x+2)) \times\frac{1}{x+2} = 0$$

Now, plugging $x=-1$ into this, I had got $${dy \over dx} = \frac{\sin^2y}{\cos y}$$

Now, here's the problem, the answer given in my book is $\frac{3}{\pi \sqrt{\pi^2-3}}$

Another book, however, lists the same answer but (it has a solution, I looked right now), and the solution states the answer to be $\bigg(\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg)_{x= -1} = 0$ inspite of listing the previous answer....(I think they didnt consider the $|x|$ in the derivative for $\sec^{-1}2x$)

My question is, what is the answer to this and how to get there, I tried searching up this for hours but havent found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugging in $x=-1$
$$(\sin y)^{\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})}+ \frac{\sqrt3}{2}\sec^{-1}(2x)+ 2^x\tan (\log_e(x+2))=0$$

$$\Rightarrow (\sin y)^{-1} + \frac{\sqrt3}{2}\cdot\frac{2\pi}{3}+2^{-1}\tan(0) = 0 \Rightarrow \color{blue}{\sin y = -\frac{\sqrt3}{\pi}, \cos y = \frac{1}{\pi}\sqrt{\pi^2-3} } $$

and if at $x=0$, $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\sin^2y}{\cos y} $ you get $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{3}{\pi\sqrt{\pi^2-3}}$

Comment: Shouldn't the value of sin y be negative of what u get?

Comment: @Techie5879 yep! Corrected.